# Recursive immutable definition with generic

Tags: typescript

I have a type definition for making a type immutable, where I had hoped it would be able to determine, all the way down, the types of the properties and make them immutable. The code for this definition is below (`Immutable`).

My problem is, when I try and use this with a generic type, the compiler determines that these types do not overlap, and so I'm not able to cast an object as immutable. **What I'm trying to do is to be able to use the definition of `Immutable` that I have, but have it work with a generic.**

If I try this without a generic, it will work fine. Equally if I change the definition of immutable (removing  `as T[K] extends (...args: Array<any>) => any ? never`) then the type casting will work with a generic. So I'd imagine it's something to do with this.

My understanding of what  `as T[K] extends (...args: Array<any>) => any ? never` is doing is saying that, if the property `K` of `T` is a function, then don't include it; but I may be wrong, I did not write this code originally.

Here is the code:

```js
type Immutable<T> = T extends string | number | boolean | bigint | symbol | undefined | null
    ? Readonly<T>
    : T extends object
    ? { readonly [K in keyof T as T[K] extends (...args: Array<any>) => any ? never : K]: Immutable<T[K]> }
    : never;

interface IWithValue {
    value: number;
}

interface IWithSelected<TData> {
    selected: TData;
}

function f<T extends IWithValue>(
    g: (x: Immutable<IWithSelected<T>>) => void,
    x: IWithSelected<T>
) {
    // This doesn't work because it doesn't believe the types overlap sufficiently
    g(x as Immutable<IWithSelected<T>>);
}

function f2<T extends number>(
    g: (x: Immutable<IWithSelected<T>>) => void,
    x: IWithSelected<T>
) {
    // Another generic using a number instead makes no difference
    g(x as Immutable<IWithSelected<T>>);
}

function f3(
    g: (x: Immutable<IWithSelected<{ a: 1 }>>) => void,
    x: IWithSelected<{ a: 1 }>
) {
    // Removing the generic removes the issue
    g(x as Immutable<IWithSelected<{ a: 1 }>>);
}

function f4<T>(
    g: (state: Immutable<IWithSelected<T>>) => void,
    x: IWithSelected<T>
) {
    // This one works
    g(x as Immutable<typeof x>);
}

function f5<T>(
    g: (state: Immutable<T>) => void,
    x: T
) {
    // This one works
    g(x as Immutable<T>);
}

function f6<T>(
    g: (state: Immutable<IWithSelected<T>>) => void,
    x: IWithSelected<T>
) {
    // This one gives as error
    g(x as Immutable<T>);
}
```

[Playground link for above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAkgWwQVxAQwEYBsoB4AqAfDALwz4xQAeIUAdgCYDOMTIATgJZ0DmMAPjDrIEGKOwEwMAe2k40dSRk49uISUzCi5k5IygAzblAaThWLMBjWYAfhgAlKGgbS6WMAUJWbALnKUNPTMMNIYAFZQAMYgPtb2AN4w7M6u7mAwANoA0jDcMADWUGDSBgFoLPg5ALqBtIwsABQAdK1o7DxM-gCC7OxongpghACUpMRDdkJQAG7iMP7Z1f6IKOjYeFVLxAC+cQvTc+wA3MDAauIGaFGwcADqnCAAFgBqaFjIsAn7M++f-sJROJTntznRaOwrjd4A9ngBlKA4GImAgAETQ6GI3xsrER0VoDH8+HR6BBZwMehinDcMAMBDqwRY90erz+UEIjX2PH8jTYGKgKyQqEwOFwzPheORDC8o3GMBm0k4DAANPsqCtYU8EUiCV5gGNsTYAPRG8hPTgsVxQJh0ADk6gA7tJ2AUpNE0MgmLBHjArTb7W6sJxZrBnqHINbQkcsGgIKxkAYjFFg+CPFzGlQYBV4EL1qLxVrJbqiKMycAKXQqTSDAAmenUeohQFidgcrk8vm0QVrEV4Ava-EoktjEjEBVK1U49UwlkDqV6g37E0wbp0aRhiQ8ejiThRGCe7h8NBCEQtvJ0NipGAINBFFhr32cRPieg3dOZ7OrYUbMWaufFwhS2AUEKyrRQDAAZk5HFuRgXl0C7HMex-fsixRJI0H8ABGGAdkAkcx0VFU1Q1Wc0OlDDsNw7xFxxZcnAQaQZkPGAwxgLc6B3PcUkYuYWDYi0mE+d8syZXNe1-MidXQrMqLwoCQMpEBqXAgAWLxoJsWD4P5btv3zP9yJlAj5SIycbGnVDpOlIh9RgQ1rGXfBzRYNxYCdF0mBEz9xJ-cBoFKGAqAU8klJU2kAFYNPbODOwFJD9M2WVR1MicSPIOyHJgJyXNCTiYA8govJgjNRISvMkpGMtQOU6sADZopgjsEPir8KskiVrOMuVx2IqdSM6wcbJo+yl1NZyLTy2BVD4srxHYZ1vLE5DRSIKrgOAIA)

But changing the definition of `Immutable`, the error goes away:

```js
type Immutable<T> = T extends string | number | boolean | bigint | symbol | undefined | null
    ? Readonly<T>
    : T extends object
    ? { readonly [K in keyof T]: Immutable<T[K]> }
    : never;

interface IWithValue {
    value: number;
}

interface IWithSelected<TData> {
    selected: TData;
}

function f<T extends IWithValue>(
    g: (x: Immutable<IWithSelected<T>>) => void,
    x: IWithSelected<T>
) {
    // no error on this one
    g(x as Immutable<IWithSelected<T>>);
}
```

[Playground link for above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgtnArsAhgIwDYQDwBUB8UAvFLlBAB7AQB2AJgM5QPABOAljQOZQA+UNRHDQRWfKGgD2krChri07Lp2DiGIYTPGJ6EAGacIdcYIwYAUFCtQA-FABKEFHUk0MIPPkvWAXKXJUtIxQkmgAVhAAxsDeVnYA3lCsTi5uIFAA2gDSUJxQANYQIJJ6pAC6fvBIqJg4uNllhAC+sVB+NBAAbqIA3ObmKqJ6KJHQMADq7MAAFgBqKBiI0PGtnQtL7UIirH0tAzTUrMOjsJMzAMoQWNFGeAAiKKiEK9bMV1HUdH64D6i7-XodNF2K4oHo8AFqPQmBMpnN1hB8AAKVpcPxIiiVBDIdBYbCwi7vG50Tz4ACUxEInUk7DoABpWpjTnDLtdPp5zBSXtYAPQ8gSScisViSMSgmbsJiuCCojFQFAw7E1PEE6asj63Ajk3ZAA)

Comment: It looks like generics themselves are working though: 
`function f4<T>(
    g: (state: Immutable<IWithSelected<T>>) => void,
    x: IWithSelected<T>
) {
    g(x as Immutable<typeof x>);
}`

Comment: @robertotomás ah yes, that's interesting. Indeed this also works `function f5<T>(g: (state: Immutable<T>) => void, x: T) { g(x as Immutable<T>);}` but this does not: `function f6<T>(g: (state: Immutable<IWithSelected<T>>) => void, x: IWithSelected<T>) { g(x as Immutable<T>); }`. Will add these to the question

Comment: Why don't you want functions to be included?

Comment: @vera no (personal/specific) reason but it's the type definition as it exists in the codebase (presumably for reasons) and so I'm working with it for now

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, `a : T` is very different from `readonly_A : Immutable<T>`

You cannot cast a to readonly_A.

Your type are correct, but the variable are not.
What you need is to *convert* a to readonly_A, which cannot be the same instance.
What you need is a readonly *copy* of your object to pass it to g function.

This looks to works :

```
function readonlyCopy <T>(something:T) : Immutable<T>  {
    const readonlyCopy :  Immutable<T> =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(something))
    return readonlyCopy;
}
```

then

```
 g(readonlyCopy(x));
```

Comment: Ah, this is interesting; I put together a playground to demonstrate to see how this works (see next comment); in this case, the type is able to be cast to an immutable version. Is the difference here that the code you have uses a generic? I believe there's a chance that this could work without cloning the object.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAkgWwQVxAQwEYBsoB4AqAfDALwz4xQAeIUAdgCYDOMTIATgJZ0DmMAPjDrIEGKOwEwMAe2k40dSRk49uISUzCi5k5IygAzblAaThWLMBjWYAfhgAlKGgbS6WMAUJWbALnKUNPTMMNIYAFZQAMYgPtb2AN4w7M6u7mAwANoA0jDcMADWUGDSBgFoLPg5ALqBtIwsABQAdK1o7DxM-gCC7OxongpghACUpMRDdkJQAG7iMP7Z1f6IKOjYeFVLxAC+cQvTc+wA3MCgkLDdpDAJ+2j+AIynNlL+ty8vUf7CouL7eztTudoDAAELXVaoTA4XDdQhAqJuNgwKg9a7vGz3GAPAA0+wwb32n38ACZ-sA9sBEXRkQT4EgoRtYcQyFRjkA

Comment: In case it helps to clarify, I believe `T` _is_ castable to `Immutable<T>` (at least in theory); the readonly aspect is only handled from typescript, so the shape of the data is the same

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i think i got it.

looking at the Readonly definition :
type Readonly = {
readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P];
};

and your immutable exception for value types :

```
string | number | boolean | bigint | symbol | undefined | null
```

i have tested readonly :

```
type ROstring = Readonly<string>; // is string 
type ROnumber = Readonly<number>; // is number 
type ROboolean = Readonly<boolean>; // is boolean 
type RObigint = Readonly<bigint>; // is bigint 
type ROsymbol = Readonly<symbol>; // is symbol 
type ROundefined = Readonly<undefined>; // is undefined 
type ROnull = Readonly<null>; // is null
```

so this declaration :

```
 readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P];
```

do identity for those types.
Immutability is so similar , we can remove exception :

```
type Immutable<T> = { readonly [K in keyof T  as T[K] extends (...args: Array<any>) => any ? never : K]: Immutable<T[K]> }
```

All cast are now working.
(except f6, but this one should crash).

Even better g(x) is working also.

[playground with bonus at the end](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgtnArsAhgIwDYQDwBUB8UAvFAN5QBOEKAJgPYB2GIUA2gNJQCWDUA1hBB0AZlFxQoKAM5iOAXSgQAHsAgMaMgBQA6XSgoBzKQC4oAQQoUUIbCgYh8ASmKE7LAPxQGEAG4QKUKbscqbwSKiYOLjyhAC+AFDxoJBQAPIYNGHI6Fh4hCTiyqrqMlLAFDwGUAA+XohwaP41UGh0dFh2zWhcBjzAzVIgDe3NiOoQwjwQNM0MiBgY8RISngBK1PRMNgRLy6aFKmoaUHRoAFYQAMbAuytklBuMzGycPPyCImKSMtHBioclKA6PSGEzmSzWWz2JwuST2KCebx+AJBEKwBDZSJ4GJQBLLQJeXz+ADciXx8T6-mEKEu0BgAHUuMAABYANRQGEQ0FItygPg5XNMcwaJPiCQpDFUFGptNgjJZAGUIFhrtM8AARFCoQg8-FSZVXVQ0faa1Ck8XCMbXLiMKDCPD-YrHBlMtkCiD4TS8gymTRlLUQUIYiK5F2Kg2qmh5GFEQg+OhcGgAGl5SlC8uZSpVRry8WcuuWAHpC2JmVwZPQIFIGAByfoAdzoFD4LSuKEQ+u4-Ur1brrYwXCJUBZ0GSVZOyIwKDAUCkiGEk0ug8lzG9miUjlJ+IM6++6PCORwYczEZzBCc5sSloY1ttwgATA6ikcZMLGhRPd7ff7VEGD1jjyzQ01XPZxYz5BNk1TdNXSAyNc3zXli3MBg6BHAIDDUfwuEuKAO0qSQ6hFAIeDKDYoDgFABFfOgoBoLgF38NRaTXDct2WHclD3LIQyPDM4LPfALzFK8rWAG1eGEABmL1t2-VBf33TFQ34081XIFBTAARlxISwLjSCU3xNM5VgtSow07TdLzMgkJLdY4DoHwCJHKBMO8CpcKoRy-BkVzyznCBWM3VjuODQ9sEA8zsEsqAdNiPTL3ia9b0kgAWPJZI4+SAz-ZS+LM7MQL02F40TIzlhMqKiqjHZEPxZDcDLGRGGgRtmykYL2IkTiwv-XIx0+JRhItMSJLtABWTKvyBH9AyU3i8n0iDyugsQbILCRGuak5vCgdq+E67d1xC46uOkBaIoIELRpvcS7wANmmuTZoU+aeIi6rgNqkrwLKqDjJg8MaoQ2yGpLJry126Bel8vd-AoJsutCi6PoA1SQfPKBTo43dUfCrFruJKBkJZKHWv2i6qA5Z5OgRptAhExIknAaAzGIMHlk0oj326lpTE2-EoEuIV6nfXkEliUkxygDMADExsYGQSE5iRubfUV8RFzR9CMYwzEcWMzF5NABd5LXReI83lmEYxNEN-B-utnq7d1kw3FYOQHYABURuByxwMx8AlkSZa4AmsAAfTKCoGCqEg0dyGPKnwYnkKh5O46gFmUnD-qIEjjWAgTiOcCL1OSZLKGi+zsPS8j1p2moXgS-z7BG46BgK-TmQO+b2vWe4evul6SUOcTnAR76buq97no+gH3P68GYYMHH0vsBX1oMBn7hSiGbfF+gPP8sjsYaAmKYZlb-LsHPy-vBoXeofvyZH6Pof88L+Y15vxa5gWM-V8P8P4n14pHdmf8IpB2JokGW7QaCRzAYeaO5QCIkHSJkDemcDBANnGgrOOdoAIKQfXGuGCMgT2wOXNOs8eZNCIScDIpCv5906BQrBbc2Fd1oXvFobRO4fxIcgyIDd55jw4VQqeko8HSP6Iw4Ry8D4jEkdg5RO9eEZ3UUI5hIio6vyvhzTBVCDGPzwaY6YOjEF6ILgA3+aRKEbzsXguxViWGn0gQ4zht8YHZ0YdTTYzBUGx3jlAdYtAng2BwXgnBH8AmRO-sRDm4TAk2BoZXPhNd-GPC2A3AR-cSApMie3fJdhZGlN4NkiJuS5HJJycwdu4jgCyKaXE+pIBo7aMKe0ze6iYnaKqaks+4w36WO6dUhpFin6aJkFMtpEyOmuPGak6hP8XEgOZshegUAhCIC8HQeskhWjIGHIPCAABHRAHImQsGEH7KAzJgDADACYYsvQWSIDQNoS4dA4CFjHAAWkuMyGmahMJSH+azIFIKFhgvHO4dwFI4BgCbP0GW5AACilyORJigBipQkBri4jtPcmsAABQFwLQVxyrIWZAXAMBSBrHAwelxpDjhIKwXY+LCXAGwFiq5GBIrYIIbg3FxiRUhKEvgCqPLDT8uxUKqh5dxWOLbuXISsqCXyoFRyYVXCKkyq8VIw1mruXauuAqwV+rb5yKNRKrhTTpVat5VavVVCt7tHtWq2+nqd5mokHKy1uqlUbymd67xi1w0BrxRavlIabX-zWaqyNEVnExqDfGxViboERqoUHDNca3WhrbvLRWDApB5o3mWu6ElK1mrkEAA)

Comment: This is really interesting; it's strange that typescript appears from your example to consider the immutable and non-immutable types to be equal; when we try and use the immutable type, practically it doesn't want to allow there to be any keys. I'll send the playground link in the next comment

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgtnArsAhgIwDYQDwBUB8UAvFAN5QBOEKAJgPYB2GIUA2gNJQCWDUA1hBB0AZlFxQoKAM5iOAXSgQAHsAgMaMgBQA6XSgoBzKQC4oAQQoUUIbCgYh8ASmKE7LAPxQGEAG4QKUKbscqbwSKiYOLjyhAC+AFASEvE8qhTCKADG0DAA6lzAABYAaigYiNCkiUk+ZRWmDIhwaP4A3PEJKQxpGdmw+UUAyhBYmao0eAAiKKiEVUlQUiMQYxA0prjTqO2dwogMY1yMUMJ4iipqGv0FJXUQ+JrVEgammlKoqqEIyOhY2Hk3YajcZ4fBOFxQHx0Lg0AA0TygSlCA0KQJWIII8Wc8ySBk0Skc7QWeKUkhkYR+kX+KLRqwmBCcO3i8UyjHeUEyaFMZ2UqnU5JRpXK9zeHwgX3CvxwAKGyzpoPBREIUJhxEREJxElZDCkdCw2gwdDx7xmEG0S2Ba0JHXaQA

Comment: yes, strange. I think this should be another stack question, may be.

Comment: I do agree that there's a separate issue to be discussed, though I'm afraid it does mean that the solution above is not workable

Comment: Seems to work in the scope that you provide.
The problems is not linked to solution i provide, because the problem exists already with OlbImmutable type.

Comment: Thank you for the bounty. I do not really understand how I win, since your problem do not look solved. Happy to have help

Comment: Definitely helped to understand the problem, though indeed it's still not solved. That being said, it may well be unsolveable!